# How to call a referenced lambda?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to call a function (lambda) stored within an alist. Below is a small snippet that demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

```
(defvar *db* '((:add (lambda (a b)
                       (+ a b)))
               (:sub (lambda (a b)
                       (- a b)))))

(defun perform-operation-on-numbers (operation a b)
  "Performs specified operation on the supplied numbers."
  (let ((func (second (find operation
                            *db*
                            :key #'car))))
    ;; TODO: Call `func` on `a` and `b`
    (print func)))

(perform-operation-on-numbers :add 1 2)
```

No matter what I do, not even `funcall` is able to let me call the lambda stored against `:add`. How should I reference the retrieved lambda as a lambda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by other answers, you are manipulating code as data, where the forms below `(lambda ...)` are unevaluated. But even with your data:

```
(defvar *db* '((:add (lambda (a b)
                       (+ a b)))
               (:sub (lambda (a b)
                       (- a b)))))
```

You can use `funcall` or `apply`, if you first use [`COERCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_coerce.htm):

> If the result-type is function, and object is a lambda expression, then the result is a closure of object in the null lexical environment.

For example, let's access the form associated with `:add`:

```
CL-USER> (second (assoc :add *db*))
(LAMBDA (A B) (+ A B))
```

The value is an unevaluated form.
You can coerce it to a function:

```
CL-USER> (coerce (second (assoc :add *db*)) 'function)
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (A B)) {536B988B}>
```

Maybe you want to walk the terms to check that the `lambda` are only using a restricted set of operations, in which case it makes sense to keep them as data. But at some point you'll want to turn these code snippets to actual functions, and you can do that with `coerce`:

```
CL-USER> (defvar *db-fns*
           (loop 
             for (n c) in *db* 
             collect (list n (coerce c 'function))))
*DB-FNS*
```

Here you compute the functions once, and can reuse them later instead of calling `coerce` each time.

```
CL-USER> *db-fns*
((:ADD #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (A B)) {536B9B5B}>)
 (:SUB #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (A B)) {536B9C0B}>))
```

(it is equivalent to calling `eval` on the lambda form)

Comment: I haven't used `coerce` a lot. This is a great idea though, I'll definitely give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: This is what eventually worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your use of `quote` lead to your inability to use `funcall`.

Look:

```lisp
(setf *mydb* '((:add #'+)
               (:sub #'-)))
;; ((:ADD #'+) (:SUB #'-))
```

I can't use `funcall`. But:

```lisp
(setf *mydb* (list (cons :add #'+)
                   (cons :sub #'-)))
;; ((:ADD . #<FUNCTION +>) (:SUB . #<FUNCTION ->))
;;
;;            ^^^^ "FUNCTION" ? That's better!          <----------
;;
```

I can `(funcall (cdr (first *MYDB*)) 2)`

Then the succinct notation is with back-quote and comma.

Comment: This is interesting. I never thought of it this way. Definitely worth a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That's not a function: it's a list beginning `(lambda ...)`.  If you want a function *have a function*, for instance by

```
(defvar *db* `((:add ,(lambda (a b)
                        (+ a b)))
               (:sub ,(lambda (a b)
                        (- a b)))))
```

or, better, don't wrap the thing in some useless baggage:

```
(defvar *db* `((:add ,#'+
               (:sub ,#'-))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'd go with option 1. Thank you!

Comment: @myTerminal It's hard to see a reason for `(lambda (a b) (+ a b))` over `#'+` in this context unless it is to make things a little bit slower and a little bit bigger.  *Perhaps* if you want to be very sure that calling the function with more than two arguments will signal an error?

Comment: Nah, this was just a dumbed-down example of what I was intending to do. :)